# How Do I Migrate From One Mercurial Server To Another Without Losing My History?

Tags: mercurial, migration

I have a project where I'm using Bitbucket as my HG server, but I've recently discovered that as a lone developer I can use Fogbugz/Kiln for free. I want to move my files into Kiln but I don't want to lose my history. I'm sure there's a dead-stupid easy way to do it, but I just don't know. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create the new project repo and do the following with your current copy of the original repo: `hg push new-repo-path`.

Then you use the new path in the future.  You can delete the bitbucket repo.

With Mercurial, all history is in every copy of the repository, including your local copies.

Comment: ok cool... then after i push, do i clone from the new repo path so that future pushes redirect there?

Comment: @Jason no - you can just edit `.hg/hgrc` and update the path of the default repository.  Any Mercurial repo can push/pull to any other copy of the same repository without problems, and there's nothing other than `.hg/hgrc` tying a repository to its original source.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already using Mercurial. I was just curious, shouldn't cloning your repository on Fogbugz/Kiln be sufficient.

```
hg clone "BitBucket Repo ..."
```

Of course, this won't copy your per-repository hgrc file. You will need to do that separately.

Another approach is to use bundle.

```
hg bundle --all bitbucket.bundle
hg clone bitbucket.bundle my_repo
```

Third approach is to push or pull from bitbucket repo to fogbugz repo.

> Setting defaults

See: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks.

Reproducing it here:

It is possible to store a default push URL that will be used when you type just 'hg push'. Edit hgrc and add something like:

```
[paths]
default-push = ssh://hg@example.com/path
```

Comment: i thought about just cloning my repo, but i want to make sure that when i `hg push` it goes to the new fogbugz repo instead of the bitbucket one

Comment: @Jason: That you should do by setting the defaults. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have already explained that right after creating a new empty repository, you can push your changes into it with `hg push http://example.com/hg/newrepo`. (Note that once you have pushed some changes into it, it will only accept changes from related repositories in the future.)

What you also seem to be wondering about also is how to then configure your local repository to push to that location by default, without needing to specify the URL every time. You can do that by editing the [default location](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-the-basics.html#id349161) in the `.hg\hgrc` file of your repository. It is a text file that you can open with notepad or any other text editor.